# Trying to Login with Selenium but its not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to login to woolworths website using selenium. But after entering email and password, when I click on login button, nothing happens. I have tried everything I can find on internet but its no use. It`s a simple login but now it is driving me crazy.
I am sharing the code below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/securelogin")
loginform = driver.find_element_by_id('loginForm')
user = loginform.find_element_by_id("loginForm-Email")
user.send_keys("myemail")
pas = loginform.find_element_by_id("loginForm-Password")
pas.send_keys("mypass")
pas.submit()
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce this manually as well. Try to use Firefox instead of Chrome

Comment: Not working. I tried both chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

To login into the website you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/securelogin')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#loginForm-Email"))).send_keys("myemail")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#loginForm-Password").send_keys("mypass")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/securelogin')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='loginForm-Email']"))).send_keys("myemail")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='loginForm-Password']").send_keys("mypass")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: woolworths]

Comment: that's not the problem.. as you can see in his screenshot, he clicked on the login button and the loading spinner appeared after instead of "login" text.

Comment: After login button is pressed, the spinner appears in place of login button text and nothing happens.

Comment: @Razvan Before the login request is sent of coarse there will be _username_ and _password_ validation through `onclick` event. So unless you provide us a demo set of working credentials we would be unable to repro the loading issue. We can only help you to invoke click on the desired button.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and all I can say that this can have 2 roots: weak internet connection or the server is a sloth.
You can try to add a wait until loading icon inside of login button disappear (you will need to create a locator for it), or, perform the click action based on javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('locator_name')[0].click();")
```

Comment: I can login to the website manually. It takes like 2 sec when login manually after clicking  the login button. But when I am trying to login using selenium, after pressing login button, the spinner replaces the text in the button and nothing happens. The internet connection is fine also.

Comment: Mmm, but if you run it on another browser, is the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

For clicking on Login button, please use this xpath :

```
login= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginForm']/fieldset/div/shared-button/button")
and then try:
login.submit()
```